# How do I fix a Gitlab Runner install error?

Tags: curl, gitlab, debian, dpkg, debian-buster

I have my own GitLab-Instance set up and wanted to install GitLab-Runner on my Instance.

I followed the docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) but I am stuck after downloading the package with `curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_x84_64.deb"`.

Because after the curl, `dpkg -i gitlab-runner_x84_64.deb` is throwing an error which says, that gitlab-runner_x84_64 is not an archive in Debian-Format, and that the dpkg-deb --control subprocess is returning errorcode 2.

How do I fix this?

My VM runs Debian 10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so it turns out that apparently the `curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_x84_64.deb"` download was defect.

I have now used a different URL (from https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/index.html) and the installation worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have a similar error in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/unable-to-upgrade-to-gitlab-ce-13-0-in-ubuntu-20-04/45488)

> It turns out the oldest version available in the repos for focal is 13.2.0. So I reverted the gitlab to bionic:
>
> ```
> deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ bionic main
> deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ bionic main
> ```
>
> To my surprise, the upgrade to 13.0.0 has just finished without problems. I can now go further to upgrade it to the latest. And switch it to focal when I get to 13.2.0.

In your case, since you are using debian 10 "buster", you might need to adjust the repo accordingly, as [in here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4584), knowing that Debian Buster is not be supported until GitLab 12.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command described [on the website](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/debian/buster/gitlab-ce_13.8.1-ce.0_amd64.deb) :

```
wget --content-disposition https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/debian/buster/gitlab-ce_13.8.1-ce.0_amd64.deb/download.deb
```

Dowloading the `.deb` package `gitlab-ce_13.8.1-ce.0_amd64.deb` for debian 10 (Buster).